# Values of columns in first table refer to column names in second table. How to pull the values from second table?

Tags: sql, t-sql

First post, have been searching extensively for a month for an answer to this and figured I would just ask the experts.

I have populated a table with patient accounts that have received services at a hospital. I am pulling columns listing the performing physician on each of their procedures. The values of those columns are sequence numbers that point me to a set of columns in a second table. The columns in the second table actually contain the physician identifiers I need.

Example:

**TABLE 1**

```
Account:       Phys_Proc1     Phys_Proc2     PhysProc3     PhysProc4     PhysProc5`

Patient1       2              5              1             4             5
Patient2       1              3              3             4             0
Patient3       2              0              0             0             0
```

**TABLE 2**

```
Account:       Physician1     Physician2     Physician3    Physician4    Physician5

Patient1       500123         500456         500789        600123        600456
Patient2       400321         500700         300876        456789        987654
Patient3       300500         800700         0             0             0
```

I need up update the records in TABLE 1 with the values from TABLE 2 where the value in TABLE 1 refers to the column name from TABLE 2.

**EXAMPLE**

Patient1 had procedure1 performed by '500456' (Phys_Proc1's value is "2" which refers to the Physician2 field in TABLE 2.)

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Even a hint at this point would give me a direction to look in. Pointing me toward a specific function name to search is better than what I have now (nothing.) I tried an extensive CASE statement but it didn't pull the values for each patient account and pulled the values from TABLE 2 for the first account and applied it to all patient records.

Comment: Personally I would redesign to correctly normalized tables and then you would not have this nightmare. I would create a patient table, a physician table and procedure table and then a table that has PatientId, PhysicianID, ProcedureId, and date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
UPDATE Table2 
SET 
Physc_Proc1 = 
    CASE WHEN Phys_Proc1 = 1 Then Table2.Physician1 
    CASE WHEN Phys_Proc1 = 2 Then Table2.Physician2 
    CASE WHEN Phys_Proc1 = 3 Then Table2.Physician3 
    CASE WHEN Phys_Proc1 = 4 Then Table2.Physician4 
    CASE WHEN Phys_Proc1 = 5 Then Table2.Physician5
    ELSE NULL 
END, 

Physc_Proc2 = 
    CASE WHEN Phys_Proc2 = 1 Then Table2.Physician1 
    CASE WHEN Phys_Proc2 = 2 Then Table2.Physician2 
    CASE WHEN Phys_Proc2 = 3 Then Table2.Physician3 
    CASE WHEN Phys_Proc2 = 4 Then Table2.Physician4 
    CASE WHEN Phys_Proc2 = 5 Then Table2.Physician5
    ELSE NULL 
END, 

PhyscProc3 = 
    CASE WHEN PhysProc3 = 1 Then Table2.Physician1 
    CASE WHEN PhysProc3 = 2 Then Table2.Physician2 
    CASE WHEN PhysProc3 = 3 Then Table2.Physician3 
    CASE WHEN PhysProc3 = 4 Then Table2.Physician4 
    CASE WHEN PhysProc3 = 5 Then Table2.Physician5
    ELSE NULL 
END, 

PhyscProc4 = 
    CASE WHEN PhysProc4 = 1 Then Table2.Physician1 
    CASE WHEN PhysProc4 = 2 Then Table2.Physician2 
    CASE WHEN PhysProc4 = 3 Then Table2.Physician3 
    CASE WHEN PhysProc4 = 4 Then Table2.Physician4 
    CASE WHEN PhysProc4 = 5 Then Table2.Physician5
    ELSE NULL 
END, 

PhyscProc5 = 
    CASE WHEN PhysProc5 = 1 Then Table2.Physician1 
    CASE WHEN PhysProc5 = 2 Then Table2.Physician2 
    CASE WHEN PhysProc5 = 3 Then Table2.Physician3 
    CASE WHEN PhysProc5 = 4 Then Table2.Physician4 
    CASE WHEN PhysProc5 = 5 Then Table2.Physician5
    ELSE NULL 
END
FROM Table2
INNER JOIN Table1
ON Table2.Account = Table1.Account
```

Note: I haven't tried this for syntax. I hope this gives you an idea on how to proceed further.

Comment: You are truly a god amongst men. This is exactly what I needed. A few minor tweaks to match my environment and it worked perfectly. Thank you, you have no idea how much of a help you have been.